# What is wrong with this proof. (Closure of unions equal union of closures)

Tags: general-topology

I found something that I don't understand.

I know it is not true that in general that:
$$\overline{\bigcup_n A_n} \subset \bigcup_n \overline{A_n}$$
Because I recently read some examples where that is not true. The problem is that I tried to prove that and I thought that it is true. This is the "proof":

$A \subset \overline{A}$ and $B \subset \overline{B}$, then we can show that $A \cup B \subset \overline{A} \cup \overline{B}$. Now, as $\overline{A \cup B}$ is the "smallest" closed set containing $A \cup B$ and $\overline{A} \cup \overline{B}$ is closed it must hold that $\overline{A \cup B} \subset \overline{A} \cup \overline{B}$. Suppose it is true that $\overline{\bigcup_{\alpha=1}^n A_{\alpha}} \subset \bigcup_{\alpha=1}^n \overline{A_{\alpha}}$.

Now, notice that:

$$\overline{\bigcup_{\alpha=1}^{n+1} A_{\alpha}} = \overline{\bigcup_{\alpha=1}^n A_{\alpha} \cup A_{n+1}}$$

So, with the same first argument we can say that (because we are dealing with a finite union of closed sets which is closed):

$$\overline{\bigcup_{\alpha=1}^n A_{\alpha} \cup A_{n+1}} \subset \overline{\bigcup_ {\alpha=1}^n A_{\alpha}} \cup \overline{A_{n+1}}$$

And with the induction hyphothesis:

$$\overline{\bigcup_ {\alpha=1}^n A_{\alpha}} \cup \overline{A_{n+1}} \subset \bigcup_{\alpha=1}^{n} \overline{A_{\alpha}} \cup \overline{A_{n+1}} = \bigcup_{\alpha=1}^{n+1} \overline{A_{\alpha}}$$

$$\Rightarrow \overline{\bigcup_{\alpha=1}^{n+1} A_{\alpha}} \subset \bigcup_{\alpha=1}^{n+1} \overline{A_{\alpha}}$$

So, this is true for all natural numbers $n$.

What is wrong with this "proof"?

Comment: There is nothing wrong. The statement is indeed true when the number of sets in the union is finite. (in that case there is even equality, not just inclusion).

Comment: But why that proof is not valid for an infinite union of sets?, as it is valid for any $n$

Comment: When you do induction you prove a statement for any finite natural number. At step number $n$ you proved the claim for $n$ sets. But there is no step in which you proved it for infinitely many sets. There is a difference between "the statement is true for any finite number of sets" and "the statement is true for infinitely many sets".

Comment: Thanks, it is more clear now. I was confused about the range of induction.